# HTML5 Elements won't display:none; in IE even when using Modernizr

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, sass, modernizr

I'm chucking together a quick splash page for users visiting my website in IE8 or below. I'm using Modernizr's .lt-IE9 class to target the document, then using this CSS (with the help of SASS) to hide my main content and show an 'IE-Warning'.

```
.lt-ie9 {
    body {
        background:none;
    }
    .container {
        display:none;
    }
    footer {
        display:none;
    }
    .ie-warning {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
    }
 }
```

Everything is working except for the display:none; on the footer element, which is of course a HTML5 element. I'm at a loss as to why it won't hide, it's not showing in the inspector or being overwritten by anything else.

Comment: I assume you are using the HTML5shiv.

Comment: Yes that is the one included as part of Modernizr.

Comment: Have you tried other styling to the footer to see if it is being applied? Can we see your HTML and the OUTPUT of your css?

Comment: Yeah it's just not adding anything at all, nothing showing in the inspector.

Comment: I've actually had this happen before... and I cannot remember what I did. Let me google something. The js is BEFORE your CSS right and the rest of modernizr is working?

Comment: I've tried both before and after my CSS declarations, and neither worked. The Modernizr documentation does say load it in after CSS though http://modernizr.com/docs/ (just search for 'shiv' and it is in that paragraph).

Comment: I remember when I was using a custom shiv once it didn't work when it ran after the CSS, but I wasn't sure about modernizr. That is very strange. Can you please post your HTML and the actual output of the css?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29619/discussion-between-guerillaradio-and-leeish)

Comment: Are you sure you're approaching this the right way? What technologies are you using which makes IE8 unsuitable? Would it be easier to fix the issue rather than introduce splash pages? While I hope oldIEs die sooner rather than later, few people use IE8 because they want to. And isn't a splash screen worse than the "best viewed with" messages we killed off a decade ago?